# geom_bar(position="dodge") is not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing some exercises with `ggplot()` and I want visualize the below dataset:

```
Cultivar Date   Weight
c39     d16     3.18
c39     d20     2.80
c39     d21     2.74
c52     d16     2.26
c52     d20     3.11
c52     d21     1.47
```

It should look like Pic1 graph
[image: pic1]

But when I use

```
ggplot(cabbage_exp, aes(x=Date, y=Weight,fill=Cultivar)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

it shows an error

> Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.

However `geom_bar(stat=”identity”)` works fine (Pic 2)[image: Pic2]

Please suggest:)

Comment: `geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")`?

Comment: `geom_col(position = "dodge")`

Comment: @ThomasK Works for me,i should have thought of it earlier. Thanks Mate:)

Comment: @Axeman...can you please  tell me..how is geom_col() different from geom_bar()?

Comment: Please go through the text and example of the [docs](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html). It's quite clear. The default `stat` is different.

Comment: Thank you...i am currently learning from R Graphics Cookbook, so facing some initial issues with regards to ggplot()

Comment: When in doubt, please consult the docs first, they are quite good and many of the examples will help.

Comment: Sure...Will do:)